# How to use __get__ to make object JSON serializable?

Tags: python, json, string, python-3.x, descriptor

I have a decorator that returns a string on `__get__`. How can I make it compatible with `json.dumps`?

```
import json

class Decorator(object):
    def __init__(self, value=''):
        self.value = value
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.value = value
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.value

class Foo(object):
    decorator = Decorator()

foo = Foo('Hello World')
json.dumps(foo)
```

This minimal example raises an exception in `json.dumps` stating that `Decorator` is not serializable. Since it is not a real string but just provide a string like interface that's not surprising. How can I make it JSON serializable using the value returned by `__get__`?

Comment: The fact `foo` is not serializable has got nothing to do with the `Decorator` class. E.g.: `class A(object): x = 3; a = A(); json.dumps(a)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extend `JSONEncoder` class to be able to handle `Foo` objects; Example almost copy pasted from [documents](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html):

```
>>> class myEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
...     def default(self, obj):
...         if isinstance(obj, Foo):
...             # implement your json encoder here
...             return 'foo object'
...         # Let the base class default method raise the TypeError
...         return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
... 
>>> json.dumps(foo, cls=myEncoder)
'"foo object"'
```